# Node, gm - JPG to PNG conversion anomaly

Tags: node.js, image-processing, graphics

I'm trying to use the following code on `ubuntu 14.04 with GraphicsMagick`:

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("resized2.png");

gm('Koala.jpg')
 .resize(200,200)
 .autoOrient()
 .setFormat('png')
 .write(writeStream, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

This results in two files being created, please see the image below:

[image]

A zero byte `resized2.png` and the correctly sized but bizarrely named [object Object] 'file'.

I tried with the following, however, same result:

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("resized2.jpg");

gm('Koala.jpg')
 .resize(200,200)
 .autoOrient()
 //.setFormat('png')
 .write(writeStream, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that instead of expecting a writeStream gm expects a filename string as the first argument of `write()`. (sadly I can't find any docs for the write function)

the result: write needs a filename, `writeStream` is an `object`. `object.toString()` is called and returns `"[object Object]"` as filename.

Meanwhile `fs.createWriteStream()` creates an empty file and does nothing else.

try this without writeStream:

```
gm('Koala.jpg')
 .resize(200,200)
 .autoOrient()
 .setFormat('png')
 .write('resized2.png', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```